# Steering a Raspberry Pi Car

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am building a PiCar with a Raspberry Pi Zero. I am using the L293D chipset to connect two DC motors and I have everything working as per this guide:

https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051

Currently I have written a rudimentary script for driving the car forward, backward, left and right. However there are a few issues. How do I steer the car left or right without moving forward or backward first. Also how can I make the car steer with just a key press of wasd and perhaps accelerate using the cntrl key? How difficult would it be to have steering a bit like car games where you hold down the accelerator to move but if you release then it slows down? Here is the code I currently have which works, but you need to press enter each time.

PiCar.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#left motor
in2 = 10    
in1 = 9     
en1 = 11    

#right motor
in3 = 24    
in4 = 23    
en2 = 25    

#setup motors 
GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en1,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(in3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en2,GPIO.OUT)

def forwards():
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(en1,GPIO.HIGH)

    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(en2,GPIO.HIGH)

def backwards():
    GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(en1,GPIO.HIGH)

    GPIO.output(in3,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(en2,GPIO.HIGH)

def left():
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(en1, GPIO.LOW)

def right():
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(en2, GPIO.LOW)

def stop():
    GPIO.output(en1,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(en2,GPIO.LOW)

#setup pwm
pwm_right = GPIO.PWM(en2, 100)
pwm_left = GPIO.PWM(en1, 100)

while True:
    cmd = raw_input("Command, w = forward / s = backward / x = stop (add a number between 0..9 for speed eg f6):")
    if len(cmd) > 0:
        direction = cmd[0]
    if direction == "w":
        forwards()
    elif direction == "s":
        backwards()
    elif direction == "a":
        left()
    elif direction == "d":
        right()
    elif direction == "x":
        stop()
    else:
        stop();

    speed = int(cmd[1]) * 11
    pwm_left.start(speed)
    pwm_right.start(speed)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after trawling the Internet I found a great solution here under Robot Car - Python Programs. Also works with the L293D. Have tested and can confirm.

http://custom-build-robots.com/ebook-download

Comment: Cool, I'm going to look into that too.

Answer (score 1):

1. To have the application continue, even when you don't press anything you can use Pygame. It reads low-level key values and the get_pressed() function returns an array of keys that are pressed at that moment.
2. the get_mods() function will return the CTRL key state like this:

   if mods & KMOD_CTRL:
3. To take acceleration into account you can keep a speed variable and increase that value with an acceleration value every few milliseconds, for as long as the forward key is pressed. When it is unpressed, decrease the speed until it is 0.
4. To move forward and turn at the same time you can send a pwm value 100 to the left wheel and 50 to the right wheel. You can do the same acceleration trick as above to have the steering increase for add long as you hold the A or D key.

Comment: are you able to write some psuedocode explaining how to do this? and tell me what libraries I need to import. how does python check if a key is held down?

Comment: You need the library pygame. 
Pygame literally checks the scancode of the keyboard, not taking any languages or keyboard layout into account.

Comment: You need the library pygame. 
Pygame literally checks the scancode of the keyboard, not taking any languages or keyboard layout into account. (which is a good thing for this purpose)
if you remove the raw_input line, the script will run continually. Then change every line where you check the direction value to something like this:
`if pygame.get_mods() & KMOD_CTRL:
 speed=200
 forwards()`
After the PWM statements, add an elif: stop();, so that it stops when you press no key at all. These are just some directions to get you going again. Please feel free to ask anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

For left movement of car, you can use the following code

The mechanism of moving car in left and right direction depends of output of left metor and right motor. If left motor is on high, the car will move on right direction and if right motor is high, the car will move on left direction.

def left():

```
GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(en1, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(en2, GPIO.LOW)
```

def right():

```
GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(en2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(en1, GPIO.LOW)
```